# how to remove 'Total' from excel while check ssas cube data

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

the rank is also using Total value of the column. how to remove that.
it's a calculation.

```
+---------------------+------------+------+
|     Row Labels      |   Change   | Rank |
+---------------------+------------+------+
| ADDERALL XR         | 20,236.00  |    7 |
| ATOMOXETINE         | 11,448.00  |    9 |
| BIPHENTIN           | 87,007.00  |    4 |
| CONCERTA            | 151,397.00 |    3 |
| CONCERTA            |            |   11 |
| DEXEDRINE           | 2,065.00   |   10 |
| GENERIC ATOMOXETINE | 17,778.00  |    8 |
| INTUNIV XR          |            |   12 |
| METHYLPHENIDATE ER  | 21,969.00  |    6 |
| METHYPHENIDATE ER   |            |   13 |
| RITALIN IR          | 40,826.00  |    5 |
| RITALIN SR          | -19,238.00 |   14 |
| STRATTERA           | -19,555.00 |   15 |
| VYVANSE             | 220,762.00 |    2 |
| Grand Total         | 534,695.00 |    1 |
+---------------------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Could you add more information? it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. And maybe format your table with this tool  http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: good question - just very badly formatted/explained! (did my previous answer to you rank question help you at all?)

Comment: Is `Rank` calculated in the cube, or in the Excel workbook? Can you please add the `mdx` code.

Answer (score 0):

In the excel sheet, right click on the area where cube data is populated, Click on the **Pivot table options**, goto **Totals and Filters** tab, and uncheck **grand totals for columns** options, and your totals will go off. It will remove totals for all columns, and you will have to sum those columns where you need totals by explicitly writing formulas for those columns.